# My firewall tells me it's preventing an access attempt to a specific machine on my LAN, but how could it know which one?

Tags: networking, firewall, lan, nat

My smart firewall tells me it's blocked an unauthorized access attempt to a specific computer on my LAN. But of course my LAN addresses are all local (10.x.x.x). So how could it possibly know which computer on my LAN this access attempt is intended for?

Is this inbound activity related or tied to some outbound activity?  Does some protocol carry some NAT translation with it?  If so, is this inbound activity randomly picking LAN addresses?

Or is the router tracking that this specific computer went to that outside IP address, and tie it back that way?

My firewall is a recent model xFinity cable modem, FYI.

Maybe this question is just academic, but I want to increase my understanding.

[image: Access attempt blocked]

---

***Update***: Here's the message with my device on it. That's all it gives, except there's an "allow access" button on it too.  The way it displays that port number, it looks like the source port (far side), but I agree that it's unclear and that's the only place I can find it.  The firewall definitely doesn't have a "SuperUser" mode!  ;-)

[image: LAN device for real]

Comment: Do you know whether the message shows the _source_ port or the _destination_ port? (The label would imply it's the source port, but showing only that and not the destination port would be useless, so I have to guess it is actually the destination port... Which still isn't great when the firewall doesn't tell you which protocol it was -- but at least there's a fairly simple explanation anyway.)

Comment: Or, since you also mention that the firewall tells you which local device it protected... is it actually showing you much more info than you left in the cropped screenshot? Could you include the entire message instead?

Comment: Nothing that’s visible on the screenshot indicates this “attack” was bound for a specific device. Please provide the full view. Note that your internal IP addresses are not security critical data.

Comment: OK, Here's a [help page](https://internet.xfinity.com/more/help/articles/Frequently-Asked-Questions#xfi-advanced-security). I don't have any port forwards on right now, so that seems like that couldn't be it.

Comment: That's an ephemeral port. It's likely that the connection was initiated by the client within your network, and that your firewall just triggered when the remote machine tried to connect back to your local machine. It could be due to a virus on the local machine or simply because someone visited a potentially malicious site on that machine.

Comment: A Malwarebytes scan reveals only [Adware.Mindspark](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/detections/adware-mindspark/) in the browser. Doesn't seem like it.